# calculating SmoothPageIndicator positioning

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, layout, user-experience

As you can see, the carousel dots aren't lining up as expected.

[image]

I am trying to get the height of the `SizedBox` above the `SmoothPageIndicator` such that the indicator will be at the bottom of the screen.

Here is my page layout:

```
SafeArea(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
        kBottomNavigationBarHeight -
        AppBar().preferredSize.height -
        PlatformDispatcher.instance.views.first.physicalSize.height*0.07,
    child: PageView.builder(
      controller: controller,
      itemCount: pages.length,
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        setState(
          () {
      hourIndex = index;
          },
        );
      },
      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
        return pages[index % pages.length];
      },
      physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 2),
        SmoothPageIndicator(
    controller: controller,
    count: pages.length,
    effect: const WormEffect(
      dotHeight: 16,
      dotWidth: 16,
      type: WormType.thinUnderground,
    ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

As you can see, I tried to calculate the height using the following formula, and failed miserably:

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
        kBottomNavigationBarHeight -
        AppBar().preferredSize.height -
        PlatformDispatcher.instance.views.first.physicalSize.height*0.07,
```

I am using the following four emulators:

- Pixel 4 API 30
- Pixel 5 API 33
- Pixel 6 Pro API 33
- Pixed XL API 33

How do I solve this?

Comment: replace SizedBox with Spacer Widget. It works like Expanded without child.

Comment: you cant use `Spacer` inside `SingleChildScrollView` @VivekChib

Comment: I think its about adaptive screen. you may read this documentation https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/responsive/building-adaptive-apps#visual-density

Comment: I didn't see that SingleChildScrollView being used in the code. My bad.